# Django - How to make session expire when browser is closed by user

Tags: django, session

I develop an app with Django
I want to manage different security aspects for connexion/authentification

first, I would like session expire when user close his browser
so, in my understanding it should be

> SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

in settings.py but it does not work 
even if I close the browser and open another browser I am connected

Comment: you should close the tab of your app and the close the browser then check. it should work. If still not working then try closing all tabs then re open. I hope that helps..

Comment: what do you mean by "close the tab of your app"?

Comment: It means the browser tab through which you have accessed you web app.

Comment: For testing, set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` in `settings.py` and see if that works.

Comment: cool, it works ! thanks !